# How stream-buffer works in C++?

Tags: c++, stream, buffer, cout

I'm testing C++ code for stream buffering. As far as my understanding goes for buffering idea, the following code should print out "Before loop " and "After loop" at the same time, even though there is delay in form of for loop. Problem is that it prints them with that loop delay. Can someone explain the reason to me? I'm passing cout as an argument.

```
void testBuffer(ostream& os){
    os << "Before loop - ";
       for(int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++){
         // waste time
       }
    os << "After loop " << endl;

    }
```

Comment: It depends on the stream and how it's implemented. For example `std::cerr` should never be buffered and should print `"Before Loop - "` right away.

Comment: From my experience most of the buffered streams either have a really small buffer or just always print.

Comment: If you want to introduce a delay, use the standard [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) function. There's a good chance `for(int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i < i++);` won't actually delay execution at all (depending on build flags/options).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The OP is saying that it prints with a delay, meaning the loop isn't being optimized away.  They expect `os << "Before loop - ";` not to actually print since they haven't flushed the buffer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There should be just i++, my bad. So, i know that this code should work the way i described, i'm using it from a lecture. Is it possible that it has something with operational system?! This code was initially tested on Mac os and i'm using windows with identical IDE

Comment: afaik as far as the c++ standard is concerned you have no guarantee when the stream is flushed other than: it is flushed when you explicitly flush it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes of course. It executes, but it should not effect the outcome in this case.

Comment: Well that's a false assumption.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, I wasn't trying to explain the lack of apparent delay by my second comment. I was presenting `sleep_for` as the safe way of introducing delay which includes mentioning that the loop is not guaranteed to delay.

Comment: @AmikoMalania Even if you had `i++` the loop might not cause a delay. Though the problem is likely that the stream is either not buffered.

Answer (score 0):

Buffers are not infinite, and in the case of non-file streams probably not even all that large.

Just because you did not write `std::flush` doesn't mean there *definitely won't* be an immediate response from the stream. If the buffer is full, it's still going to flush. It's just that you're not forcing an *early* flush.

Furthermore you *may* conceivably see `std::cout` behaving like `std::cerr` (which basically disables buffering) in debug modes. I don't know whether any implementation does this.

Moral of the story:

- if you *need* the output immediately, flush;
- if you *need* it later, write it later;
- if *and only if* you don't care either way, do it the way you've done it.

Comment: In what sense do you mean infinite/finite?! Is it from time viewpoint, so if i reduce looping it will be written soon or length of the string - which i doubt to be the case.

Comment: @AmikoMalania It was hyperbole ;) It seems you expected that the buffer would _definitely not flush_, but if it's already full that's not the case, and the only way your expectation can be fulfilled in general is if buffers have infinite size.

Comment: I don't fully get it but thanks for your time and answer!